# Merge one dataframe value based on another following the hierarchic order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given two dataframes which you may download from [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6md9m10f6md5y1iwvyoo4/test1.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=bl7yts55wz0y4t4t1g43rpzar):

df1:

```
  category  category_id big_class  big_class_id small_class  small_class_id
0        A            1        a1            11         aa1             111
1        A            1        a2            12         aa2             112
2        B            2        b1            21         bb1             221
3        B            2        b2            22         bb2             222
4        B            2        b3            23         bb3             223
```

df2:

```
   item small_class  small_class_id  ... big_class_id  category category_id
0  aaa1         aa1           111.0  ...         12.0         B         2.0
1  aaa2         aa2           112.0  ...         11.0       NaN         NaN
2  bbb3         NaN             NaN  ...          NaN         B         2.0
3  bbb4         bb3           223.0  ...          NaN         A         1.0
4  bbb1         NaN             NaN  ...         23.0         A         1.0
```

You can find data in `df2` doesn't follow the hierarchic order of `df1`, which means `['small_class', 'small_class_id', 'big_class', 'big_class_id', 'category', 'category_id']`  ie., for row of `aaa1`, its `small_class` is `aa1`, then, `big_class` and `category` should be `a1` and `A`, instead of `a2` and `B` based on `df1`, same logic for row of `bbb1` in `df2`, if its `big_class` is `b2` then `category` should be `B` instead of `A`.

My trial code:

```
df = pd.merge(df2, df1, on = 'small_class', how = 'left')

df['category'] = df['category_y'].fillna(df['category_x'])
df['big_class'] = df['big_class_y'].fillna(df['big_class_x'])
    
df.drop(['big_class_x', 'category_x', 'category_y',
       'big_class_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df3 = pd.merge(df, df1[['big_class', 'category']], on = 'big_class', how = 'left')
df3['category'] = df3['category_y'].fillna(df3['category_x'])

df3.drop(['category_y', 'category_x'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Any ideas how could acheive this in more concise way? Thanks.

The expected result:

```
   item small_class  small_class_id  ... big_class_id     category category_id
0  aaa1         aa1           111.0  ...         11.0            A           1
1  aaa2         aa2           112.0  ...         12.0            A           1
2  bbb3         NaN             NaN  ...          NaN            B           2
3  bbb4         bb3           223.0  ...         23.0            B           2
4  bbb1         NaN             NaN  ...         22.0            B           2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
condition_1_mask = (~df2['small_class'].isnull())
df2.loc[condition_1_mask, ['big_class', 'category', 'category_id', 'big_class_id']] = df2[['small_class']][condition_1_mask].reset_index().merge(df1, how='left', on=['small_class'])[['big_class', 'category', 'category_id', 'big_class_id', 'index']].set_index('index')
condition_2_mask = ((df2['small_class'].isnull()) & (~df2['big_class'].isnull()))
df2.loc[condition_2_mask, ['big_class', 'category', 'category_id', 'big_class_id']] = df2[['small_class', 'big_class']][condition_2_mask].reset_index().merge(df1, how='left', on=['big_class'])[['big_class', 'category', 'category_id', 'big_class_id' ,'index']].set_index('index')
print(df2)
```

Out:

```
   item small_class  small_class_id big_class  big_class_id category  \
0  aaa1         aa1           111.0        a1          11.0        A   
1  aaa2         aa2           112.0        a2          12.0        A   
2  bbb3         NaN             NaN       NaN           NaN        B   
3  bbb4         bb3           223.0        b3          23.0        B   
4  bbb1         NaN             NaN        b2          22.0        B   

   category_id  
0          1.0  
1          1.0  
2          2.0  
3          2.0  
4          2.0
```

Comment: Sorry, `big_class_id` in `df2` seems not updated based on `df1`.

Comment: Check it now, I have made edit to the code.

Comment: If I have another more columns ie., `middle_class` and `middle_class_id` between `small` and `large`, how should I add more condtions?

Comment: I think u can try updtaing the masks accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly - assuming that `df1` contains the most up-to-date data and you'd like to use it to update the values in `df2`, using the [pandas update method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df1 = df1.set_index('small_class')
df2 = df2.set_index('small_class')

df2.update(df1)

df1 = df1.set_index('big_class')
df2 = df2.set_index('big_class')

df2.update(df1[['category', 'category_id', 'big_class_id']])
df2.reset_index()
```

Out:

```
  small_class  item  small_class_id big_class  big_class_id category  \
0         aa1  aaa1           111.0        a1          11.0        A   
1         aa2  aaa2           112.0        a2          12.0        A   
2         NaN  bbb3             NaN       NaN           NaN        B   
3         bb3  bbb4           223.0        b3          23.0        B   
4         NaN  bbb1             NaN        b2          23.0        A   

   category_id  
0          1.0  
1          1.0  
2          2.0  
3          2.0  
4          1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your code it seems generates empty as `df`. You can find the expected result in downloaded file.

Comment: hi @ahbon I made a small mistake, `update` happens in place so we do not need to assign it to a new dataframe. Please try the above code again

Comment: For last row, `b2`'s `id` should be updated to `22`, instead of `23`, `category` and `category_id` should be `B` and `2.0` since the `big_class` is `b2`.

Comment: Hi @ahbon, again made some small changes. Have not updated the output as the files you've provided seems a little different with some extra columns.